# How to catch Subview events in the Controller?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-events

BackboneJS app built with RequireJS modules.

A *View* has multiple instances of *subView*. Click events in a *subView* should run *Controller* methods.

Initialization order requires *View* module in *Controller*, so requiring *Controller* module in *subView* would create a circular dependency.

I would prefer to create Events to convey data to Controller. Considered two options:

1. View listens to subView events and fires own Events, listened by
   Controller;
2. Have a third app-global object, subViews trigger
   events on that object, Controller listenes on that object?

What is the best pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marionette has [event bubbling](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/events.html#event-bubbling) in place. For example if a view triggers "some:event", you can listen it on collection view as "childview:some:event".

If you have really deep views structure, then "childview:...childview:some:event" starts to look really bad and then you might consider three options: manually bubble them, use global message bus like "backbone.radio" or passing down some entity to fire events on it.

I personally feel bad about global bus and prefer to have for each meaningful part of application something that would implement [mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)/[observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern. Basic implementation might be state model, created in controller (or router) and passed in all the views below - then any of them can change something in state or listen to changes.

Actually as Controllers were deprecated in Marionette 3, it might be a good idea to move all the controllers logic inside these state models. Unfortunately as Backbone community is on decline I can't find any good resources on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

If is only one case, option 1 is right.
But if is a common operation, with multiple events and needy by many views: the 2 option may be better.